# Granger Causality and positive semidefiniteness

Tags: self-study, granger-causality

Suppose that we have vector $y_t = (z_t, x_t)'$ for $t = 1, 2, \dots, T$. Let $\Omega_t$ be the information set available at time $t$ and $z_t(h|\Omega_t)$ be optimal $h$-step predictor. $\Sigma_z(h|\Omega_t)$ denotes forecast MSE matrix.

We say that $x_t$ helps to predict $z_t$ ([Granger Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality)) if 
$$\Sigma_z\left(h|\Omega_t\setminus\{x_s|s\leq t\}\right) - \Sigma_z(h|\Omega_t)$$
for at least one $h = 1,2, \dots$ is positive semidefinite and 
$$\Sigma_z(h|\Omega_t) \neq \Sigma_z\left(h|\Omega_t\setminus\{x_s|s\leq t\}\right).$$
The definition is clear for me. $x_t$ helps predicting $z_t$ if the covariance matrix of the prediction without using $x_t$ is bigger then when we use $x_t$ in a matrix sense.

My confusion is more about interpretation of the semidefinite matrix. By definition $m\times m$ symmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite iff for any $m\times 1$ vector  $z$ 
$$z'Az \geq 0.$$

Let $A \equiv \Sigma_z\left(h|\Omega_t\setminus\{x_s|s\leq t\}\right) - \Sigma_z(h|\Omega_t).$ So what is the intuition that if $x'Ax \geq 0$, then I can conclude that $x_t$ helps in predicting $z_t$?

---

**Edit**: Just to clarify, the question is more about the concept that the variance of one random vector $x$ (denote it by $\Omega_x$) is greater than for the other random vector $y$ (denote it by $\Omega_y$) if the difference between their covariance matrices, $\Omega_x - \Omega_y$ is psd.  As one more example, consider GLS and OLS estimators in a linear regression setting, $\hat\beta_{GLS}$ and $\hat\beta_{OLS}$ respectively. We say that the GLS estimator is more efficient if $B \equiv \Omega_{OLS} - \Omega_{GLS}$ is psd matrix. That is, for any vector $z$ it holds that 
$$z'Bz \geq 0.$$
In other words, covariance matrix $\Omega_{GLS}$ is smaller in a matrix sense than $\Omega_{OLS}$. What I am looking for is an explanation/intuition of why the case when the matrix $\Omega_{OLS} - \Omega_{GLS}$ is psd implies that the GLS estimator is more efficient then the OLS? Maybe another formulation: what does it mean for one matrix to be smaller then the other?

Comment: @William - if you expand that second point a little you'll have the reason, and you can convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive semidefinitness of the difference of two matrices is the concept that is analogous to the difference being non-negative for unidimensional entities.

In particular, a positive semidifinitness matrix has all its diagonal elements non-negative. Diagonal elements here represent same-period forecast MSE's so positive definitness says that the forecast MSE without $x$ will be equal or greater compared to when we include $x$.

So this is a weak form of Granger Causality. We would want the difference of the two matrices to be positive definite in order to have strictly greater same-period MSE's

Comment: Good point with diagonal elements being positive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following comes with the caveat that I know nothing about Granger causality, just about how positive semidefinite matrices relate to covariances of random variables. According to @jbowman in the comments, this observation is apparently correct regarding the motivation for using positive semidefinite matrices in the context of Granger causality.

**1.** I think your definition of positive semidefiniteness is missing [the condition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveSemidefiniteMatrix.html) that the matrix $A$ needs to be symmetric (assuming $A$ has real entries -- the more general condition, when $A$ possibly has complex entries, is that $A$ be [Herimitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix)). Although [some authors disagree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non_symmetric_matrices).

The analogy is with bilinear forms, for which questions of positive/negative semidefiniteness only make sense in the context of symmetric bilinear forms (I think -- since there is a one-to-one correspondence between symmetric bilinear forms and quadratic forms, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_quadratic_form)).

Matrices $A$ can be used to represent both linear transformations and bilinear forms even though all three are different objects -- this is because they are all vector spaces of the same dimension, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/412454/327486) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20438/115093).

**2.** I bring up the likely implied requirement that the matrix $A$ be symmetric for the following reason:

I imagine the condition on $A$ being symmetric and positive semi-definite has something to do with the fact that [any covariance matrix](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/ttic101-07/lectures/Gaussians/Gaussians.pdf) $A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, and any symmetric positive semidefinite matrix could represent the covariance matrix of some multivariate distribution. See, for example also [(1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-always-symmetric-and-positive-definite)[(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114072/what-is-the-proof-that-covariance-matrices-are-always-semi-definite)[(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)[(4)](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~davidc/pubs/tt2015_dac1.pdf)[(5)](https://shiyuzhao.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/why-covariance-matrix-is-positive-semi-definite/)[(6)](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/covariance-matrix)[(7)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~i707107/HW2.pdf) (from the first page of my Google search.)

Technically, the above only addresses one direction of my claim -- that any covariance matrix is positive-semidefinite. It does not address the other direction of my claim -- that any positive-semidefinite matrix is the covariance matrix for *some* random vector (it shouldn't necessarily be clear which, and in general there is no reason to believe the distribution will be unique.) For that, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489632/is-every-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix-a-covariance-of-some-multivaria) and Exercises 2-4 outlining a proof [here](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/courses/monte.carlo/alt4.7d.pdf).

Basically, the covariance matrices are symmetric because covariance is a symmetric relationship.

And they are positive semi-definite because the variance of a random variable is always non-negative and since [symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255622/symmetric-matrix-is-always-diagonalizable).

The converse holds because you can always "rig" a simple enough distribution (e.g. multivariate Gaussian) to give you a covariance matrix with the entries you want, as long as those entries constitute a symmetric, positive-semidefinite matrix.

---

Anyway, my guess is that the condition in the definition of Granger causality, that the matrix $A$ be positive semi-definite (and symmetric), probably has a probabilistic interpretation and motivation. The most likely such interpretation or motivation is that it is supposed to be a stand-in for an arbitrary covariance matrix, which is what positive semi-definite matrices are.

Your question also suggests this interpretation too:

> $x_t$  helps predicting $z_t$ if the covariance matrix of the prediction without using $x_t$ is bigger then when we use $x_t$ in a matrix sense.
>   ...
>   So what is the intuition that if $x′Ax≥0$, then I can conclude that $x_t$ helps in predicting $z_t$?

This is just a guess, which is why I initially posted it as a comment, but I was encouraged to post it as an answer by another user, which suggests that my guess might in fact be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very interesting links. I apologies, but I forgot to mention that the matrix $A$ is supposed to be symmetric. I made some edits and hopefully the question is more clear now.