# requirements for simulating a covariance matrix

Tags: correlation, covariance, stochastic-processes, covariance-matrix, volatility

I was wondering, is any positive semidefinite matrix a valid covariance matrix?

My problem is the following. I want to simulate a stochastic covariance matrix where the log-volatility (log of square root of variance) and the correlation are simulated separately according to some stochastic process. If I can ensure that the resulting covariance matrix is at all times positive semidefinite, is it a valid covariance matrix process?

To make things clearer, let's assume I want to simulate a $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix process. I would proceed by simulating two log-volatility processes and one correlation process:
$$\log\sigma^1_t = f(\theta^1, t)$$
$$\log\sigma^2_t = f(\theta^2, t)$$
$$\rho_t = g(\theta^3, t)$$
where the $\theta$'s are some parameters. Then, given $\sigma^1_t = e^{f(\theta^1, t)}$, $\sigma^2_t = e^{f(\theta^2, t)}$, $cv_t = \rho_t \sigma^1_t \sigma^2_t$, I build the covariance matrix process
$$
X_t = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
(\sigma^1_t)^2 & cv_t  \\
cv_t & (\sigma^2_t)^2  \\
\end{array}\right]$$
My question: if by choosing proper $\theta$, I can ensure that $X_t$ is at all times positive semidefinite, is it a valid covariance matrix process?

Comment: <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-always-symmetric-and-positive-definite> could bue useful.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215647/919 for the multidimensional generalization of your approach.