# Why absolute value of eigenvalues are used in PCA or LDA?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition

In PCA and LDA techniques, eigenvectors with the $k$ largest eigenvalues give principal components. However, **when selecting these eigenvalues, are they to be sorted by the absolute value (regardless of sign) of the eigenvalues or just the eigenvalues themselves (with sign) ?**

That is, are the eigenvectors decided by the order of *dominant eigenvalues*? And are thus just the *dominant eigenvectors*?
[*Dominant eigenvalues* as defined [here]](https://ergodic.ugr.es/cphys/LECCIONES/FORTRAN/power_method.pdf)

If yes, can you provide a simple intuitive explanation of why sign of eigenvalue does not matter.

I found some implementations doing so.

Comment: The covariance matrix used for PCA does not have negative eigenvalues!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the comment. Could you briefly elaborate why?

Comment: That is explained elsewhere on the site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-always-symmetric-and-positive-definite

Comment: [Covariances are variances.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142472/919) In particular, the eigenvalues are variances (of the eigenvectors).  Because variances are expectations of squares and squares (by definition) are never negative, the eigenvalues cannot be negative.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I now understand why this would be the case for covariance matrices in PCA. However, is the same applicable for the scatter matrix ( inv(Sw).Sb ) of multi-class LDA?

Comment: Those matrices are explicitly sums of squares, so they too must be positive semidefinite.